# I want to track changes (review comments/edits) made to a document that we are displaying on a web page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, collaboration

I want to track changes (review comments/edits) made to a document that we are displaying on a web page. What is the best way to do it other that Google Docs/Dropbox and Microsoft Word Online?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Version Control, perhaps Git...

Comment: Hello Ryan, actually we will be providing an HTML document to the user. There we want a functionality where the user can add/edit text in the document, add comments to it or reply to other comments just like how it works in Microsoft Word.We tried the Google API and WOPI too, but its saving our data on their servers. We are looking for an API or a mechanism which won't save our data on their cloud or external servers.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info, at this moment I think that you and your team has shared document, that you are editing together and you want to track changes. I can propose for you three easy solutions.

1. Learn markdown(it's readlly simple) and use source control, for example git. For learning markdown and git I think you need about 4-12h. From my point of view it is very good, free and easy solution.

Small intro to git - minimum set of commands, also you can use UI client, but I think better to learn with console and than start using UI

```
git init
git remote add origin master https://github.com/yourRepository
git add *
git commit -m "description of the update"
git push
```

2. Another one is evernote. Evernote allows you to create shareable documents(notes), similar to google docs, and in premium account(costs 70 $/year) you can make snapshots of the notes and later compare them similar to version control. The big advantage of evernote - it is easy to use and you will get UI similar to word and other familiar to you(I guess) text editors. Moreover overnote have a lot of functionlity for team organizations. I steek to evernote in a week.
3. Attlassian Confluence. I can't tell you lot, because personally I'm not active user of(usually I'm only read content), but I can say it is great tool. **Also it is used in my team.** Costs 10$/20$ a month.

All solution will allow to have shared, organized documents with tracking and managing changes history. For my personal organazation tasks evernote and git were enough, switched to evernote because it more human friendly, but source control and especially atlassian provide much more powerfull, usefull posibilities.

Comment: Hello Nikita, Thanks for the quick reply. We will be providing an HTML document to the user. There we want a functionality where the user can add/edit text in the document, add comments to it or reply to other comments just like how it works in Microsoft Word.We tried the Google API and WOPI too, but its saving our data on their servers. We are looking for an API or a mechanism which won't save our data on their cloud or external servers.

Comment: @Sachin You can use git api for tracking changes and comments to the doc will be stored as separate object that belongs to doc. { body, comments[]}. And comment { pos, user, text, doc}. Pos - describes the position of  the comment, f. e. It can be char index wherr user have clicked when creating comment.